# Convex hull in projective space

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, projective-geometry

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb R\mathbb P^n$ be a closed connected set that does not intersect every hyperplane. If I choose any affine chart containing $S$, I can consider its convex hull, and it seems reasonable that this operation should not depend on the particular chart. Is there some good way to see this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider two hyperplanes $[X],[Y] \subset \mathbb{R}P^n$, defined by two linear hyperplanes $X,Y \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, such that $S$ is contained in each of the two affine charts $\mathbb{R}P^n - [X]$, $\mathbb{R}P^n - [Y]$. It follows that $S \subset \mathbb{R}P^n - ([X] \cup [Y])$.

The subset $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} - (X \cup Y)$ has four components, and these determine in a two-to-one fashion the two components of $\mathbb{R}P^n - ([X] \cup [Y])$: each component $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} - (X \cup Y)$ determines a component of  $\mathbb{R}P^n - ([X] \cup [Y])$ that I'll denote $[W]$, consisting of all points $[A] \in \mathbb{R}P^n$ represented by an open ray $ A \subset W$ based at the origin.

Of the two components of $\mathbb{R}P^n - ([X] \cup [Y])$, one of them, say $[W]$, contains your set $S$. Given two points $[A],[B] \in [W]$ represented by rays $A,B \subset W$ as above, the set of positive linear combinations $sa+tb$, $a \in A$, $b \in B$, $s,t>0$ also lies in $W$, and so each of the affine charts $\mathbb{R}P^n - [X]$, $\mathbb{R}P^n - [Y]$ defines the same segment $\overline{[A][B]} \subset \mathbb{R}P^n - ([X] \cup [Y])$, consisting of all points in $\mathbb{R}P^n$ of the form $[sa+tb]$.

This shows that the convex hull of $S$ as defined in each of the affine charts $\mathbb{R}P^n - [X]$, $\mathbb{R}P^n - [Y]$ is the same.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking another approach could be to use duality: for any closed connected set $C \subseteq \mathbb R\mathbb P^n$ not intersecting every hyperplane, I define the dual $C^* \subseteq (\mathbb R\mathbb P^n)^*$ as the closure of the set of hypeplanes that do not meet $C$. Then the convex hull of $C$ should simply be $(C^*)^*$, which clearly does not depend on the chart. Is this correct?